# Can I convert this expression into a streams API expression in Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Here is the code snippet:

```
List<Double> dataLeft, List<Double> dataRight;
double sumLeft = 0, sumRight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataLeft.size(); i++) {
  sumLeft += dataLeft.get(i)*(dataLeft.size() - i);
  sumRight += dataRight.get(i)*(dataRight.size() - i);
}
```

dataLeft and dataRight are the same size.

Comment: can you add more data? what you're trying to do, an explanation of the code, etc.

Comment: You are looping from `0` to `dataLeft.size()`. Is it supposed to be the same as `dataRight.size()`? Are `sumLeft` and `numRight` initially zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you won't gain much. You'll even lose in readability, IMHO

```
sumLeft += IntStream.range(0, dataLeft.size()).mapToDouble(i-> dataLeft.get(i) * (dataLeft.size() - i)).sum();
sumRight += IntStream.range(0, dataLeft.size()).mapToDouble(i-> dataRight.get(i) * (dataRight.size() - i)).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
private double sum(final List<Double> data) {
    final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final int n = data.size();
    return data.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d * (n - index.getAndIncrement())).sum();
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
sumLeft += sum(dataLeft);
sumRight += sum(dataRight);
```